# I'm using Sencha Cmd to compile an APP with and error that I can't understand

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm trying to compile a Sencha Touch APP in iOS environment but I got this error message that I could not understand. I though it was related to conflict file but it is not. The message is not clear. If somebody has got this message before I'll be very happy to hear from you.

I'm using Touch 2 and Sencha Cmd 5.0.2.270

```
[INF] Concatenating output to file /Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/build/temp/production/Tradebook/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js

[INF] writing content to /Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/bootstrap.js

[INF] appending content to /Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/bootstrap.js

[INF] appending content to /Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/bootstrap.js

[INF] appending content to /Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/bootstrap.js

[INF] Appending content to /Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/bootstrap.json

[INF] Concatenating output to file /Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/cordova/www/app.js

[INF] merging resources into /Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/cordova/www/resources

[INF] merged 0 resources into /Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/cordova/www/resources

[INF] merging resources into /Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/cordova/www

[INF] merged 0 resources into /Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/cordova/www

[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime

identical ../css/app.css 

[INF] Copying page resources to /Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/cordova/www

[ERR] 

[ERR] BUILD FAILED

[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to compress input

[ERR]   at java.ut

[ERR] il.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)

[ERR]   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.

[ERR] match(Pattern.java:4604)

[ERR] 

[ERR]   at java.util.regex.Pattern$C

[ERR] harProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)

[ERR]   at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)

[ERR]   at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)

[ERR]   at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)

[ERR]   at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)

[ERR] 

[ERR] Total time: 13 seconds

[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:

/Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:394: The following error occurred while executing this line:

/Users/marcocastro/Documents/TradebookApp/tradebook_dev/.sencha/app/page-impl.xml:209: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to compress input
```

Thanks,
Marco Castro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is usually thrown when your CSS is getting compressed and the compressor encounters some bad syntax. Paste your `app.css` file into a validator and fix any errors (missing semicolon?) that show up.

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input